# Any way to retrieve winrt::Microsoft.UI.Xaml::Window from HWND, WindowId or AppWindow?

Tags: winapi, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I created a window through CreateWindowEx in a WinUI 3 application, so I didn't have a Window object at first.

Using the window handle, I'm able to get WindowId and thus AppWindow. However, I couldn't find any document on how to get Window other than declare it directly.
https://github.com/ACGNnsj/WinUI3CppWinRTDemo/blob/3477dedd9404e15689278aa9c2eab734fae20316/OCR/MainWindow.xaml.cpp#LL88C3-L88C8

Comment: You can't get a WinUI3 Window from a Win32 Window (handle). You must create a WinUI3 Window first, and then you can get its handle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no existed `winrt::Microsoft.UI.Xaml::Window` which associates with the native window in your sample.

Also, there is no APIs to get the associated `winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window` from the native window or WindowId as @SimonMourier and [the question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1181058/winui3-how-to-set-id-or-a-custom-property-to-winui) said.

I have submitted a feature request about this. You can also submit an issue at WindowsAPPSDK GitHub [Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues).